# MSBuild Deploy Website

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I've a very large VS2012 web site project (not web application) and am trying to automate it's deployment. Multiple developers will be working on this site. Checking-in/out. Is there a way to deploy only checked-in files instead of the whole site?

Answer (score 0):

We have recently automated dozens of reasonably large websites using Octopus Deploy it's great ,very powerful and you could get a single website continuously deploying on check-in with the free community version. If that's where you interested in going. (continuous deployment)

Not sure about only deploying changed files.. that seems like unnecessary work?